# Android socket: buffer is null

Tags: android

Please help me in my code below. It throws the error: Android socket: buffer is null. Can you tell me what is wrong?

```
 try {
                    socket = new Socket("217.16.10.21", 1991);
                    out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.write(("285|SIP|0200|**4536780670138355*000000*1000***1309181650****000094*130918165044**1408***0918*****901301654144**300*************000000023834****00400013*65432100400013 ******P920035595*952*******************************************************************************").getBytes());

            byte[] buffer = null;
            int is=socket.getInputStream().read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            socket.setSoTimeout(500);

            String message=new String(buffer, 0, is);
            //in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8192);
             out.close();

            //String message=in.readLine();
            textaff.setText(message);
            in.close();

            //socket.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+message, 2000).show(); 

         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "erreur"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "erreur 2 "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Comment: I don't know the error also. What error is it then?

Comment: post your log cat trace here

Comment: While logcat would be nice, I believe the error is in the question title - at least that fits the obvious mistake in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
      byte[] buffer = null;
      int is=socket.getInputStream().read(buffer, 0, 1024);
```

Will not work, as you have not allocated a buffer for the .read() method to store results in - in fact you have explicitly set it to null.

You need to do something such as

```
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

to actually allocate your buffer.

Comment: i have changed that but isn't resolve. know i go to use url for to send my message because socket as so complicated

Comment: If you are abandoning the approach please delete the question, otherwise post the updated error log.

Answer (score 0):

Use this listener to get incoming messages:

```
public Emitter.Listener handleIncomingMessages = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                String message = null;
                String imageText;
                try {
                    message = data.getString("message").toString();
                  Log.v("messageeeeeeeeeee",message);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // return;
                }

                addMessage(message);

                try {
                    imageText = data.getString("image");
                    addImage(decodeImage(imageText));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    //return
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After `out.write(("285|SIP|0200|**4536780670138355*000000*1000***1309181650****000094*130918165044**1408***0918*****901301654144**300*************000000023834****00400013*65432100400013 ******P920035595*952*******************************************************************************").getBytes());`

Write:

```
socket.shutdownOutput();
```